# Mule 2 Way HTTPS Authentication

Tags: ssl, mule

I have a Mule application which needs to talk an external server over HTTPS using 2 way SSL authentication.

My question is: How to enable Server Certificate verification in Mule ? It seems, by default Mule doesn't verify Server's Cert. I am using Mule v 3.3.0.

For example: '-k' option in curl disables server's cert verification.

In similar way, is there any configuration parameter by which I can enable/disable Server's cert verification ?

Thanks
Jai

Comment: Hello Jai. I have the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449417/ssl-authentication-not-works-in-mule-esb-project-illegal-parameter

Comment: But I am trying to connect in mule processor. Do you remember the solution?

Answer (score 2):

For Mule versions before 3.6, the HTTP transport supports configuration of the trust store used by the HTTP outbound endpoint to determine whether the certificate presented by an HTTPS server should be trusted.

To provide a key store that contains the certificates of servers you need to trust, provide the `<https:tls-server />` to the `<https:connector />`, and reference that connector in your `<https:outbound-endpoint />`:

```
<https:connector name="myHttpsConnector">
  <https:tls-server path="truststore.jks" storePassword="supersecure" />
</https:connector>

<flow name="someFlow">
  <https:outbound-endpoint host="remote-host" port="443" path="/api" connector-ref="myHttpsConnector" />
</flow>
```

The blog post linked in clare's answer explains this a bit, from both the server side and the client side.  You can also refer to the [HTTPS Transport Reference](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/34X/HTTPS+Transport+Reference), although it doesn't explain the use of tls-server vs. tls-client.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this [blogpost](http://ricston.com/blog/configuring-https-mule/). It will show you how you can configure mutual authentication in Mule. HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the response but my case is different. My Mule app is the client which talks to a remote server via HTTPS. Here I need to validate the cert of the remote server i.e. authenticate the server. In my case, the server I am talking to has changed its RootCA from a knownCA to their ownCA which is not available in the default jks store. Even after the remote server has changed their root CA my ESB app is working fine where as when I try to send a https request using curl then it fails saying server certificate verification failed. I have both keystore and truststore defined in my ESB app.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the HTTP Request connector in Mule >= 3.6.0 to use a trust store you create that contains the certificate(s) of the server(s) you need to trust using [TLS Configuration](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/TLS+Configuration).

It might look something like this:

```
 <tls:context name="tlsContextForServiceFoo">
    <tls:trust-store path="serviceFooServerCertificates.jks" password="supersecure"/>
    <tls:key-store path="myClientCertificates.jks" keyPassword="extrasecure" password="ultrasecure"/>
 </tls:context>

 <http:request-config name="twoWayAuthServiceFooConfig"
                      protocol="HTTPS"
                      host="services.pentagon.gov" 
                      port="443" 
                      tlsContext-ref="tlsContextForServiceFoo" />

 <flow name="useServiceFoo">
     <http:request config-ref="twoWayAuthServiceFooConfig" path="/api/doStuff" method="POST" />
 </flow>
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan for the response. So this is not possible in Mule CE v3.3.0?

Comment: Yes that's possible too.  I'll add another answer for Mule 3.3, and you add that detail to the question so others can find it :)

Comment: Thanks Ryan. That would be great. Can you please share the solution for Mule CE v 3.3.0 asap.

Comment: Hi Ryan, Did you get a chance to get this code working on Mule CE v3.3.0. If yes, then can you please share that configuration code snippet with me. Thanks a lot for your help. Really appreciate it. Thanks Jai

Comment: Sure.  Don't forget to update the question so that others can search for the version number as well.

Comment: Hello guys! Need help in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449417/ssl-authentication-not-works-in-mule-esb-project-illegal-parameter