# SSL authentication not works in Mule ESB project (illegal_parameter)

Tags: java, ssl, https, mule

I wrote some code which authenticates in HTTPS server over SSL. It working fine.

Now I have to move this part to my Mule ESB project.

Here is my working method:

```
public boolean authenticate() {
    try {
        System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");
        System.setProperty("com.sun.net.ssl.enableECC", "false");

        CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
        manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
        CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);

        URL url = new URL("https://...");
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setUseCaches(false);
        con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        con.setReadTimeout(5000);

        // KeyStore
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("PATH/TO/.P12/file"), "P12password".toCharArray());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "P12password".toCharArray());
        // ---

        // TrustStore
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        trustStore.load(new FileInputStream("PATH/TO/.JKS/file"), "JKSpassword".toCharArray());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
        // ---

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSLv3");
        context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

        con.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());

        con.getContent();
        CookieStore cookieJar =  manager.getCookieStore();
        List<HttpCookie> cookies = cookieJar.getCookies();
        for (HttpCookie cookie: cookies) {
            if (COOKIE_NAME.equals(cookie.getName())) {
                COOKIE_VALUE = cookie.getValue();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

In Mule ESB project I call **authenticate** in processor:

```
@Override
public MuleEvent process(MuleEvent event) throws MuleException {
    MuleMessage message = event.getMessage();

    try {
        String payloadString = new String(message.getPayloadAsBytes());
        LOGGER.info("\nMessage payload:\n" + payloadString + "\n\n");

        String xml = extractXMLFromSOAPMessage(payloadString);
        LOGGER.info("\nXML: " + xml + "\n\n");

        if (authenticate()) {
            //send request to server
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("EXCEPTION: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return event;
}
```

On this line `con.getContent();` exception is raised: **SSLException: Received fatal alert: illegal_parameter**

This error also appeared in my JAVA project. But adding these parameters helped:

```
System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");
System.setProperty("com.sun.net.ssl.enableECC", "false");
```

Both JAVA and Mule are on the same machine.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Sorry for my english (:

---

**Solution is turned out to be very simple.**

`System.setProperty` not working in Mule project.

So all JVM parameters can be configured in MULE_HOME/conf/wrapper.conf.

Here is my solution:

```
wrapper.java.additional.16=-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=FALSE
wrapper.java.additional.17=-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.enableECC=FALSE
```

Thank to **Vijay Pande**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting JVM parameters as described in [mule documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/passing-additional-arguments-to-the-jvm-to-control-mule).

Comment: I am new in Mule, so I found the way to pass parameters in command line when starting mule. But you're right - these exact what I need.